# How can I exit a loop in python when a raspberry pi gpio button is pressed?

Tags: python, button, gpio

I want to build a script that runs a motor in a loop. When a button is pressed the program should exit immediately the loop and continue with the if statement. With this script I can control the motor loop but the problem is that if i press the button it only works if the loop part is in a given moment. I think I need a listener in the script to trigger immediately when the button is pressed.

```
import pygame
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import Button
from gpiozero import Motor
from time import sleep

btn1 = Button(20)
btn2 = Button(21)
motor = Motor(4, 14)

pygame.init()
while True:       
    while True:
        motor.stop()
        music = pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/sound1.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        sleep(3)  #working time  
        motor.forward()
        sleep(3)  #pause
    
        if btn1.is_pressed:
           pygame.mixer.music.stop()
           print('pressed')
           motor.stop()
           music = pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/sound2.mp3')
           pygame.mixer.music.play()
           sleep(3)  #working time   
           motor.forward()
           sleep(3)#pause
        
        if btn2.is_pressed:
           pygame.mixer.music.stop()
           print('pressed')
           motor.stop()
           music = pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/sound3.mp3')
           pygame.mixer.music.play()
           sleep(3)  #working time     
           motor.forward()
           sleep(3)#pause
```

Comment: Have you already looked at https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/? Maybe `wait_for_edge()` with a timeout helps.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the behavior you want. You said, "When a button is pressed the program should exit immediately the loop and continue with the if statement", but if you *exit* the loop there is no `if` statement to continue (as written, your program will simple terminate, because there is nothing after the `while` loop).

Comment: I want the program to execute the if statement when the btn is pressed. Has it is now it works but not immediately.

Comment: Use a callback function instead of loop